# Determining the sign of the directional derivative and the partial derivatives on a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

This is the question:
[image]

The solution says:

a) The surface is given by $z=f(x,y)$

If we see in graph as we move towards $\vec{u}=<5,0>$, $z$ increases, thus $D_{\vec{u}}f(2,-4)$ is positive.

I'm not sure what it means to 'move toward <5,0>'. Does that just mean move from the point (2,-4) towards the point $(5,0)$ in the xy plane? And how do we know that z increases? In a contour plot we can normally see numbers but in this case I don't see anything.

Similarly, for c) the solution says:

z increases rapidly, thus $D_{\vec{u}}f(2,-4)$ is positive.

Again, how do I know it's increasing 'rapidly'?

Also the solution for d) is:

At $f(2,-4)$ z is neither minima nor maxima as we can see in the graph thus the answer is NEI.

How do I know that it's not a minima or maxima? And what does that mean in terms if $f_{xx}$? I.e. how do I solve this versus finding the answer for $f_{yy}$. The only thing the solution says for e) is: Same reason as d)

Lastly,

Are these the correct answers:

a) $D_{\vec{u}}f(2,-4)$ is positive

b) $D_{\vec{u}}f(2,-4)$ is positive

c) $D_{\vec{u}}f(2,-4)$ is positive

d) NEI

e) NEI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure what it means to 'move toward <5,0>'. Does that just mean move from the point (2,-4) towards the point (5,0) in the xy plane?

There are two ways to *interpret* an ordered pair $(x,y)$ in the plane:

- as the coordinate for a "point" on the plane
- as a [Euclidean vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) on the plane

Such distinctions are used in many calculus textbooks, e.g., Stewart's Calculus.

In your context, the first interpretation is written as $(x,y)$. For instance, $(-2,4)$ is a point in the plane.

The second interpretation is written as $\langle x,y\rangle$. Any nonzero Euclidean vector can be visualized as an "arrow" that has length and direction. Arrows that are parallel, equivalently, that have the same direction and same length, are representing the same (Euclidean) vector. One such arrow representing $\langle x,y\rangle$ is one that is pointing from the origin $(0,0)$ to the point $(x,y)$.

So $\vec{u}=\langle 5,0\rangle$ is not a point, but a vector. "Moving toward $\vec{u}$" in your exercise means "moving (in the $xy$-plane) from the point $(2,-4)$ in the direction of $\vec{u}$".

> And how do we know that z increases? In a contour plot we can normally see numbers but in this case I don't see anything.

What you see is the *graph* of a function (of two variables). Each point on the graph, has the 3D coordinate $(x,y,f(x,y))$.

The graph in the $z$-direction tells you when the function increases/decreases. The figure below is another example.

> how do I know it's increasing 'rapidly'?

It is increasing "rapidly" if the surface is very steep.

> How do I know that it's not a minima or maxima?

(It does not make sense to say "*a* minima/maxima". These are plurals. One may say "a minimum/maximum". ) In the picture, you have a (local) min/max when you have a lowest/highest point.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! so for part a), if we are moving in the 'x-direction' since we have the vector <5,0> i see that the surface looks like its going 'downhill' so why does it say that the function z is increasing?

Comment: @user130306: you are probably looking at the wrong answer. If you are in the y-direction, then it is increasing.

Comment: so should it be 
a) decreasing
b) increasing
c) increasing

Comment: I'm still confused about a) though. because it's going downhill and then uphill

Comment: @user130306: Directional derivative only tells you the behavior "near" the point.

Comment: got it, thanks. also what about parts d) and e)? does $f_{xx}$ need to be a minimum or maximum for it to be positive or negative? and then what is the difference in finding $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$

Comment: @user130306 $f_{xx}$ or $f_{yy}$ alone won't give you enough information regarding min/max. You need the [second derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

Comment: sorry I don't think i understand. What info do I need/what info is given from the diagram about $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$? and what is the difference between finding $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$? Essentially, how do i solve for parts d and e

Comment: To find the sign of $f_{xx}(2,-4)$, you need to know how fast $f_{x}$ changes near $(2,-4)$, which is hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: @user130306: you don't have enough information to determine the sign of $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$.

Comment: thanks again for all of your answers. just to clarify, the answers should be:
a) decreasing
b) increasing
c) increasing
d) NEI
e) NEI

Comment: @user130306: a)-c) are asking about the sign of the derivatives, not monotonicity of the function.

Comment: oops I meant to say 
a) negative
b) positive
c) positive
d) NEI 
e) NEI
I just upvoted and I'll accept your answer too!